# JSF + Spring + Hibernate + Existing Project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf

Here's the thing.

I'm starting with JSF + PrimeFaces + Spring + Hibernate.

**The problem is:** We have a desktop application with everything created and prepared, but now we're moving to the web.

Well, when I try to load the applicationContext

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

It comes out with this

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.planner.dao.Dao at
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714) at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) ... 69 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.planner.pov.dao.AcaoDaoImpl]
 for bean with name 'acaoDao' defined in URL [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/planner/dao/Dao at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1141)
```

Well, the class `"com.planner.dao.Dao"` belongs to another project, I've already put the project in the build path, but it isn't reconizing.

Is there another configr. to do beyond importing the project?

Comment: are you sure that the JAR containing the Dao class is in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory?

Comment: No, actually there's no such jar, there's another project, called plannerUtil, which has this class. Should I export the jar and include it into WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are building your project, but yeah, ultimately the class needs to be on the classpath when Tomcat runs - which means it's either in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib as a JAR. If you are running things through your IDE, that might make it strange

Comment: In this case I think there's no problem in put the file in the lib, 'cause it's an util lib, I mean, nothing must be changed there. I'll try this when I get back to work. Thanks, matt b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am doing Spring + JSF project. It is work for me. Just try as below:

web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

faces-config.xml

```
    <application>
        <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>   
    </application>
```